# Does Google AppEngine store binary data in the datastore as plain 8-bit or as UTF-8?

Tags: google-app-engine, encoding, google-cloud-datastore, overhead

I guess the title says it all, but let me elaborate a little:

Basically, if I store (uniformly distributed) 8-bit data into the AppEngine Datastore, can I expect to use up 1 Byte of storage for every 1 byte in my `byte[]`, or is there some encoding overhead, like for example 50% overhead if it was UTF-8 encoded (since values 128..255 take up 2 bytes)?

In the docs it says:

```
BlobProperty - Uninterpreted byte string
```

Not sure if this means 8-bit bytes (uninterpreted byte) or if this implies some encoding (string)...

Unfortunately I can't find the source-code for the `setStringValueAsBytes(...)`-method in the `PropertyValue` class. It probably holds the answer...

PS: This question is probably independent of whether you use Python, Java, Go, or PHP, but in case it matters: I'm using the Java API.

Comment: What you see in source code probably bares no resemblance to what/how data is stored in the underlying datastore.  For instance for all we know they don't unpick the protobufs when storing the data.  You should direct your questions to google.

Comment: @TimHoffman The problem is that Google has moved the AppEngine support here (see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/Z6XN_64cA7w/Jf1OcUK4cF0J). So, in a way, I am directing the questions to Google, since they have some of their developers check this site periodically to answer questions (at least so my hope)... :) Also, while this question is maybe a bit technical, I'd assume that it should be highly relevant to everyone using AppEngine, since a hidden 50% storage overhead can make quite a bit of difference in your monthly bill...

Comment: Yes but this is a question of how the backend works, I would post it on the group and see what sort of response you get there.  I have been using appengine since it came out, knowing exactly how it is stored won't change how it works, you either accept the overhead (whatever it is) or move to another platform.  My gut feeling is the data/entity  is actually stored as a blob (probably protobuf).  Otherwise much of the semantics make no sense.  So in answer to your question I would look at how your specific data is encoded as a protobuf, that could show you the actual overhead.

Comment: @TimHoffman Well.. there's a lot of overhead that you can avoid or reduce if you know about it. For example if they do store data as UTF-8, I could instead encode all my binary data as 7-bit data before saving it, then the overhead is only 14% instead of 50% for 8-bit data... A 24% reduction in the storage bill can be quite significant. I'd definitely take it if I can... Good idea to check the protobuf, btw! Makes very good sense. And I think I can get at it easily with a custom Delegate override (not sure if this is Java only or can be done in Python as well). I'll do that and report back...

Comment: If you don't need to index your binary data (I assume not) then why not compress it?  Is it compressable?  Not sure what a custom Delegate is ;-)  It's easy to play with protobufs in python. I gave up on java when I left Sun in the 90's ;-)

Comment: @TimHoffman It's already compressed. :) That's why it would be so painful if UTF-8 blows it up by 50% again. In fact, since I'm using a custom Range-Coder for the compression, it would be trivial for me to compress the data to 7-bit-values rather than 8-bit-values. Just need to know if I need to do that... :) I guess I could just store a large data-set in the DataStore and see how much it costs me. Just thought someone here might know the answer off hand...

Comment: For completeness Markus has shown you can round trip binary -> UTF-8 -> binary  someone may find this useful.  http://pastebin.com/dUyiFjTq

Comment: Unfortunately the only given answer so far doesn't conclusively show whether this worry is justified or not. It does however make me think it's not. So, until a better answer comes along (unlikely, it seems), I'll accept this one, but I'll change it if needed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This info isn't entirely published, but Google has mentioned that the HRD is built on top of BigTable, and we also know that internally Google isn't really using BigTable, but Megastore, a more advanced development.

Now we don't really know exactly what the HRD is running on, but I think if you read up on how BigTable and the Megastore work, you might get a pretty good idea.

http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html

http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36971.html

Now to answer your question, I have no idea why you'd think Google would store binary data as UTF-8.  It's a retarded idea to begin with, and it would be pretty retarded for Google to implement it that way.  So I highly doubt they'll do that.

More realistically, most data storage systems have some minimum block size that is allocated for any block of data.  The BigTable whitepaper mentions that it's configurable but it defaults to 64KB.  We don't know if the HRD uses this default or some other tuned value.

In any case, I don't think you should worry about your binary data being stored as UTF-8.  That's extremely unlikely.  However, it's highly likley that your data will take up some minimum block size.  Keep in mind that your entities are stored along with their attribute names, so there's going to be that overhead.  But most likely your overhead will be your entity squeezed into the lowest block size rather than any UTF-8 worries.  It's realistic to worry that your attribute names might by stored in UTF-8, so I'd avoid having extended characters in the attribute names.

Comment: What you're saying makes good sense and I used to think this way, too. The only reason I've been having doubts is that they talk about Strings everywhere, which in today's world usually implies unicode support, i.e. some form of encoding. Even the function in the API source for saving binary data is called `setStringValueAsBytes(byte[] ...)` rather than the function for saving Strings being called `setBinaryValueFromString(String ...)`. Of course, it'd be quite inefficient to add the encoding, but, looking at the API, it wouldn't be the first inefficient thing I'd find...

Answer (score 1):

**FINAL UPDATE:**

I had some time to actually test this out by first creating 1024 entities, each with a Blob-property consisting of 100KB of random 8-bit data, waiting **FIVE** days for all the statistics to update in the AppEngine console, and then replacing the properties on each entity with 200KB of random 8-bit data. The difference in ***Datastore Stored Data*** under ***Quota Details*** and the difference in ***Total Size*** under ***Datastore Statistics*** both was 100MB exactly, so no overhead. If the data was UTF-8 encoded, the difference would have been 150MB.

So the answer is:

**The AppEngine Datastore stores 8-bit binary data as plain 8-bit bytes WITHOUT encoding.**

Good...

One side note: "1 GByte" of ***Datastore Stored Data*** in the quotas corresponds to 1024<sup>3</sup> bytes (the original definition of GB, which is now often called GiB), not 10<sup>9</sup> (the metric interpretation of Giga). Yay! 7.3% more storage for our money! And that's why I like Google better than Western Digital... :)

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I finally did find some sparse documentation to shed *some* light on this question:

The datastore defines a set of data types that it supports: [str, int32, int64, double, and bool](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown#anc-notation).

This part of the documentation states that "[i]nternally, all **str** values are UTF-8 encoded and sorted by UTF-8 code points".<sup>1</sup>

Now, the Python<sup>2</sup> documentation of the [Types and Property Classes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses) defines the [class Blob](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#Blob) as "a subclass of the built-in **str** type" and says that "this value is stored as a byte string and is **not** encoded as text".

While this is far from 100% clear (does "not encoded as text" really mean "not encoded as UTF-8"?), it seems to suggest that the data does remain as 8-bit bytes in the datastore when physically saved.

Rather than saying that this is a better answer than @dragonx's, I will take this as further evidence that he is correct, especially since I completely agree with his statement that *"[it would be] a retarded idea to begin with, and it would be pretty retarded for Google to implement it that way"*.

Maybe one day I'll do an actual test. Until then, I will hope that Google indeed is not being retarded. 50% storage-cost overhead on any binary data in the datastore should be painful enough for them to try to avoid...

*Asides:*

*<sup>1</sup> This is why I was worried about this topic in the first place.*

*<sup>2</sup> This is probably why I missed this info. The [equivalent Java docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types) don't really mention this.*

**UPDATE:**

Found some more supporting evidence:

Half way through the ["Entities Table" section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown#anc-entitiestable) at the end of the "Properties" section, it says:

"Internally, App Engine stores entities in protocol buffers, efficient mechanisms for serializing structured data; see the [open source project page](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) for more details."

The open source project contains a file called [CodedOutputStream.java](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/CodedOutputStream.java) that (I think) is responsible for actually assembling the binary data that makes up the stored protocol buffer. It defines two methods: [`writeString(...)`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/CodedOutputStream.java#L223) and [`writeByteArray(...)`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/CodedOutputStream.java#L267), which both call their respective `write...NoTag(...)` methods.

In [`writeStringNoTag(...)`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/CodedOutputStream.java#L418) we finally find the line that does the UTF-8 encoding for Strings:

```java
final byte[] bytes = value.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

This line does not exist in [`writeByteArrayNoTag(...)`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/CodedOutputStream.java#L459).

I **think** this implies the following:

- When I store a Blob, it ends up using the `writeByteArray(...)` method as I see no other reason for its existence and the [Blob class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.googlecode.objectify/objectify/4.0b1/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Blob.java) stores its data internally in a byte[] rather than a String.

  => So no encoding here...
- As `writeStringNoTag(...)` performs the UTF-8 encoding for Strings, it is likely that **any** encoding is done by the protocol buffer library.

  => So no further encoding later either...

Now, is all this enough to contradict "[i]nternally, **ALL** *str* values are UTF-8 encoded" and "Binary data [...] is a subclass of the built-in *str* type", which explicitly implies that binary data is also UTF-8 encoded?

I think so...